# Convolution of measures with a linear transformation

Tags: stochastic-processes, linear-transformations, convolution

The task:
Let $T:\mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R^d$ be a linear map. For $\mu, \nu \in M^1(\mathbb R^d)$ (so $\mu,\nu$ are probability measures), I have to show:

$T(\mu\ast\nu)= T(\mu)\ast T(\nu)$

So we have defined the convolution of measures as $\mu \ast \nu:=A(\mu \times\nu)$, with $A: \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R^d$,
$(x,y)\mapsto x+y$

So I have: $T(\mu)\ast T(\nu)=A(T(\mu) \times T(\nu))$ and

$T(\mu\ast\nu)=T(A(\mu \times\nu))=A(T(\mu \times \nu))=A(T(\mu) \times T(\nu))$, because $A,T$ are linear transformations. Is it okay that way, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think $T(\mu \times \nu)$ is not well-defined because the dimensions don't fit. ($T$ maps $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mu \times \nu$ lives on $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$.)